# Where on the last record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table:

```
PasswordHistoryId    ClientId    Password     CreationDate (dd/MM/YYYY)
  1                     1          abcd              05/01/2023
  2                     1          xyz               11/08/2022
  3                     2          efg               11/12/2022
```

I want to check if the latest password set has been expired.  A password is considered as expired if it has been created more than 90 days ago.

I have the below SQL to check if a password has expired:

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 -- Returns 1 if password has expired
FROM PASSWORD_HISTORY CHP
WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY, CHP.CreationDate, GETDATE())) > 90
AND CHP.ClientId = 1
ORDER BY CHP.CreationDate DESC
```

However this returns me 1 because of the second line in the table where the password was set on the 11th of August 2022 and it has already been expired.  I need to do the comparison on the latest record based on the creation date.

Any idea of how I can do this?

Comment: The above where will simply return `1` if there is *at least* one row in the last 90 days (note that `WHERE` clause isn't SARGable and shouldn't be written like that; use date boundaries not `DATEDIFF` on a column in the `WHERE`) and the value of `ClientId` is `1`; it doesn't check it the *latest* row has the value. Instead use a CTE/Derived table to filter to the latest row first, and *then* check the value of that row.

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(CreationDate), GETDATE()) > 90 THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS expired
FROM PASSWORD_HISTORY 
WHERE ClientId = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/AEu6Sf1j).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just check if they have a record where the password *hasn't* expired - e.g., if they have a password less than or equal to 90 days, then don't flag them.

No sorting or other functions required.

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT *
   FROM PASSWORD_HISTORY CHP
   WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY, CHP.CreationDate, GETDATE())) <= 90
       AND CHP.ClientId = 1
   )
SELECT 'Password expired';
```

**Edit: Sargability - change WHERE to use indexes**

The above (and potentially in other answers) is a non-sargable query. It has to do the calculation for every row even if you have an index.

If we calculate the cutoff/criterion date instead, then just compare with the data directly, it allows use of indexes if you have them.

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT *
   FROM PASSWORD_HISTORY CHP
   WHERE CHP.CreationDate >= DATEADD(day, -90, CAST(getdate() AS date))
       AND CHP.ClientId = 1
   )
SELECT 'Password expired';
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it will return 'Password Expired' even if there are no records at all. Up to OP to see if that is acceptable or even possible in this case.  (or one more IF EXISTS can be added to double check).

Comment: @NenadZivkovic - to be honest I considered this a feature rather than a bug. If this was just a 'log' and they had password elsewhere, then they should use that instead of this. But of course, it does depend on their data.

Answer (score 0):

Just move DATEDIFF check to SELECT statement instead of WHERE:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, CHP.CreationDate, GETDATE())) > 90 THEN 1 END
FROM PASSWORD_HISTORY CHP
WHERE CHP.ClientId = 1
ORDER BY CHP.CreationDate DESC
```

This will return NULL, though, if password is not expired. If you want to return nothing, you do need to use CTE or sub-query:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHP.CreationDate DESC) RN
  FROM PASSWORD_HISTORY CHP
  WHERE CHP.ClientId = 1
)
SELECT 1 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, CreationDate, GETDATE())) > 90
```